# How to solve this linear hyperbolic PDE analytically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve this equation analytically?
$$
u_t = k u_{xx} + \frac{k}{c} u_{xt}
$$

I attempted to solve it for a finite domain and homogeneous B.C with separation of variables but it got very ugly, with complex eigenvalues. I'm wondering if the equation could be solved with the method of characteristics? Or if there is a coordinate transformation which converts this to an easier PDE?

I am interested in solving the equation for a sine function initial condition. Either infinite or finite domain would be okay, whichever is easier.

Comment: Have you tried the Fourier transform in the $x$ variable?  Or the Laplace transform in the $t$ variable?

Comment: So I write my solution in the form $u=T(t)X(x)$ and found that the $T$ variable is just simple exponential decay, but when I tried doing Fourier series for the $X$ variable it got too messy when trying to find the eigenvalues.

Comment: Once $T(t)$ is known, substituting it back into the PDE gives:
$$
X(x) = {k \over T'(t)} X''(x) + {k \over c} X'(x),
$$
which, for each fixed $t$,  is a 2nd-order linear homogeneous ODE in $X(x)$ with constant coefficients.  Can you attack this ODE without resorting to Fourier series?

Comment: After separation of variables, I have two ODE's: $T'=-\lambda k T$ and $X''=-\lambda X + \lambda \frac{k}{c} X'$. The Fourier series is necessary to figure out what $\lambda$ is. If I have boundary conditions of $X(0)=X(L)=0$, then I know $\lambda^2 v^2 - 4 \lambda$ must be less than zero in order to satisfy the boundary conditions. Typically in these problems, you then find a list of $\lambda$ values that satisfy the B.C's. Here I had trouble finding the $\lambda$ 's.

Comment: I was a bit imprecise in the last comment, the Fourier series is how you write the solution in terms of $\lambda$, not how you find $\lambda$.

Comment: Putting of finding $\lambda$, first write: $T(t) = T(0) e^{-\lambda \, k \, t}$ and substitute it onto the ODE I wrote down:
$$
X = {k \over -\lambda \, k T(0) e^{-\lambda \, k \, t}} X'' + {k \over c} X'.
$$
For a fixed $t$, this ODE has the form:
$$
X = a X'' + b X',
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constant.  The latter ODE can be solved, in terms of $a, b, X(0)$, and another boundary value of $X$, without using Fourier series.

Comment: After plugging in $T=T(0)e^{-\lambda k t}$ I have $$X=-\frac{1}{\lambda} X'' + \frac{k}{c} X'.$$ Solving: $$X=c_1 e^{r_1 x} + c_2 e^{r_2 x} $$ where $$r=\frac{k \lambda}{2 c} \pm \frac{\lambda}{2} \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{c^2}-\frac{4}{\lambda}}$$. Given $X(0)=X(L)=0$, $r$ must be complex, so $$0<\lambda<4 \frac{c^2}{k^2}$$. Plugging in the $X(0)$ BC gives $c_2=0$, and the $X(L)$ BC gives $\frac{n^2 \pi^2}{L^2} = \frac{\lambda}{2}^2 ( \frac{k^2}{c^2} - \frac{4}{\lambda})$. But solving for $\lambda$ this runs into contradiction with previous inequality $$0<\lambda<4 \frac{c^2}{k^2}$$. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the coordinate transformation $x=x_*$ and $t=t_*-\frac{1}{2c} x_*$ transforms this equation into the damped wave equation, which has well-known solutions which can be obtained through separation of variables.